# Apache web server custom index kubernetes

Tags: apache, kubernetes

I have deployed a apache web server on kubernetes cluster using standard httpd image from dockerhub. I want to make changes to index file so that it prints the container id instead of default index file. How can i achieve this?

Comment: This very much depends on the docker image that you are deploying. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Hello, have you tried to use the lifecycle hook (`postStart`) that would run after your `Pod` started and add the hostname to your `index.html` (`$ echo $HOSTNAME >> htdocs/index.html`? Please take a look here on how it could be added: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question:

> How can I have a `Apache` container in Kubernetes that will output the id of the container in the `index.html` or other `.html` file.

One of the ways how it could be handled is by a `lifecycle hooks` (specifically `postStart`):

> `PostStart`
>
> This hook is executed immediately after a container is created. However, there is no guarantee that the hook will execute before the container ENTRYPOINT. No parameters are passed to the handler.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Containers: Container lifecycle hooks: Container hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks)*

---

As for the example of such how setup could be implemented:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache
  labels:
    app: apache
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apache
        image: httpd # <-- APACHE IMAGE
        # LIFECYCLE DEFINITION START 
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $HOSTNAME > htdocs/hostname.html"]
        # LIFECYCLE DEFINITION END
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Taking a specific look on:

- `command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $HOSTNAME > htdocs/hostname.html"]`

This part will write/save a hostname of the container to the `hostname.html`

To check if each of `Pod` has the `hostname.html` you can create a `Service` and run **either**:

- `$ kubectl port-forward svc/apache 8080:80` -> `curl localhost:8080/hostname.html`
- `$ kubectl run -it --rm nginx --image=nginx -- /bin/bash` -> `curl apache/hostname.html`

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Configure pod container: Attach handler lifecycle event: Define postStart and preStop handlers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers)*

Comment: I cannot run sh as it shows permission denied. however i can run hostname command directly

Comment: @user2636464 please attach the steps that you are following as well as the `YAML` definition. It should shed some light why you are getting permission denied.